# Read CSV file sent to Laravel route

Tags: php, laravel, csv, file

I'm sending a CSV file via curl to an endpoint handled in Laravel.

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: text/csv' -d "prices=@${file}" 'http://www.thissite.com/getprices'
```

The route is

```
Route::post('getprices', [
    'uses'       => 'PriceController@getPrices',
]);
```

But I'm not sure how to open and read the file. The function is

```
public function getPrices(Request $request)
{
   $file = $request->file('prices');
    
   \Log::info(print_r($file->extension(), true));

    return $this->response([], Response::HTTP_OK);
}
```

I've also tried

```
public function getPrices()
{
   $file = $this->getRequest()->file('prices');
    
   \Log::info(print_r($file->extension(), true));

    return $this->response([], Response::HTTP_OK);
}
```

But neither one works. $file is null. Can anyone help me out here. I haven't been able to find anything on how to receive a csv file through a laravel route.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: i'm not sure it can be done all in one go like that, i think you'll need separate functions to save the file which is uploaded, then retrieve it from the local filesystem to read it

Comment: Can I still send the file to a Laravel route to be saved? If I can do that, I can use a job to process the file.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked

curl request:

```
curl -F "prices=@${file}" 'http://www.thissite.com/getprices'
```